# Fill foreign key column with values from different table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I think I'm a bit in over my head here - really appreciate any help! :)

I have two tables in two mysql-databases:

```
Database A.Table A
id (int)
name (varchar)

Database B.Table B
id (int)
name (varchar)
foreign key1 (int)
foreign key2 (int)
```

I would like to make a MySQL query like SELECT * FROM, so that the result will still be correct, even if some extra columns are added later. However, I would like the foreign keys in Table B to be replaced with the corresponding varchar name from table A. Both foreign keys point to the same table, but may differ, because they represent where a person is, and where he belongs.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblA RIGHT JOIN tblB ON tblA.id = tblB.foreignkey1
```

But it adds another column to the result set, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

When query tbl.B like so SELECT * FROM tbl.B (add magic I'm looking for here), the end result should be something like so:

```
*--------*----------*--------------------------*---------------------------*
|tblB.id | tblB.name| foreign value1 from tbl.A | foreign value2 from tbl.A|
*--------*----------*--------------------------*---------------------------*
```

Comment: Please clarify "I would like to make a MySQL query like SELECT * FROM, so that the result will still be correct, even if some extra columns are added later.". *Adding* columns to a table never impacts existing `SELECT` queries, so I must be understanding it wrong.

Comment: What I mean is, I would rather not "Select tbl.value as name" with all of the columns, so that if I add anotherone column later on, it will automatically be a part of the result set :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question either. What column is is adding? How would your output look like using the above tables?

Comment: I've answered in the question, and drawn a neat little table. I couldn't draw it down here :D. Do you understand me now? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do things like this:

```
SELECT tblB.id, tblB.name, tblA.* -- all fields in tblA
FROM tblA RIGHT JOIN tblB ON tblA.id = tblB.foreignkey1
```

... but this is pretty much all I can think of. Unfortunately, you must either use `SELECT *` or `SELECT [each and every column]`, there is no alternative.